# Push to Remote URL with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have installed the latest [MSysGit 1.6.3](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) preview and [TortoiseGit 0.6.2](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) on my Windows XP PC. I also have created a --bare repository on my server which can be access through http (using WebDAV as authentication system).

I can successfully log into my server's git repository from a browser. I have created a local repository on my PC and the initial commit.

I have looked everyone and I still cannot find **how to add a remote URL to TortoiseGit and push my local repository to that address**.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the context menu, select "TortoiseGIT" -> "Push ...". Right of the "Remotes" entry there is a "Manage" button. There, choose "Git" -> "Remotes" in the tree. There you can input Remote URLs.

Comment: is there a way to make this the default? I have a test machine that shouldn't have a local .git, it should only pull/push to the remote repo

Comment: @Martin: default tasks should be automated as much as possible. How about creating a short script that uses the msysgit commandline to pull/push? (http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)

Comment: Push... is not in every context menu. Simpler way to do this. TortoiseGit > Settings > Git > Remotes. Settings is always in the context menu.