# Transfer GIT changes between 2 repositories

Tags: git, github

I have 2 private GIT repositories.One for the development and other for the production.The users of development repo cannot access the production repo. So my question is, how to transfer the latest changes of development repo's into production repo ? This transfer will be done by the third person who has the access to the both repositories.

**More Details :**

The initial repository is the production one.After that create a development repo by using that.Developers will clone the dev repository and do the changes and then commit it to the dev repo.After that another person will try to merge those changes into the production repo.But at that time there is no option to select the production repo.It always try to push for the original repo (i.e. dev repo).So how can I sort out this issue ?

Comment: Do you mean that you've go two *remotes*? Surely the two repositories have some shared history? How did you set them up initially?

Comment: @Chris The initial repository is the production one.After that create a development repo by using that.Developers will clone the dev repository and do the changes and then commit it to the dev repo.After that another person will try to merge those changes into the production repo.But at that time there is no option to select the production repo.It always try to push for the original repo (i.e. dev repo).So how can I sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the dev remote is set as your default/up-stream remote. So when you do 'git push' it only pushes to the dev remote. You can list your remote repositories:

```
git remotes -v
```

then

```
git push [remote-name] [localbranch]:[remotebranch]
```

Will push to an explicit remote.

Comment: Do you know how to do this by using tortoisegit ?

Comment: @Sampath Yes, just change the remote before you finalize the push. http://joelabrahamsson.com/remote-branches-with-tortoisegit/ or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959365/push-to-remote-url-with-tortoisegit